# Vignette in Package Documentation

Tags: r, package

I wrote a vignette for an R package of mine. It is built without any errors, using both `devtools::built()` and the tool built into RStudio with the vignettes option selected. The html output file is placed in the `vignettes` directory, but it does not show up in the list printed by `vignette(all = T)` and the *User guides, package vignettes and other documentation* link is not added to the documentation.

As recommended on [this](https://r-pkgs.org/vignettes.html) site, I already reinstalled the package using `devtools::install()`, made sure that the directory is called `vignettes`, and checked whether the vignettes were excluded in `.Rbuildignore` (it contains `^.*\.Rproj$` and `^\.Rproj\.user$`).

This is the (anonymized) header of the Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Introduction to my package"
author: "John Doe"
date: "May 23, 2021"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
bibliography: ../inst/REFERENCES.bib
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction to my package}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r, include = F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>"
)
```
````

Is there any other setting that requires modification?

Comment: Is the .Rmd file in vignettes ? To my memory, the source file is in vignettes and it html is compiled everytime you build your package.

Comment: @Gowachin Yes, the Rmd file is in vignettes. As I mentioned in the question, the html file is indeed compiled and placed in vignettes. The problem is that R does not list the vignette thereafter, neither in the package documentation, nor using the `vignette()` function.

Comment: Well...I though this was working on my package but I have the same issue...However `{pkgdown}` manage to find it when building documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution, from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/browsevignettes-mypackage-saying-no-vignettes-found/68656).
You need to force installation of the vignette when installing your package.

Example with local package :

```
remotes::install_local(build_vignettes = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

Example where the package is on github :

```
remotes::install_github('account/repository', build_vignettes = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

*`force = TRUE` is here because we already have the last version of the package and force installation*

I bet you can set this option in Rstudio, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: I used `devtools` instead of `remotes`, i.e. `devtools::install_github('account/repository', build_vignettes = TRUE, force = TRUE)`. But it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah devtools and remotes are really similar package, You can use both of them to instal local or dev packages.